# Storing objects with unique identifiers ( primary keys )

Tags: swift, realm

Hello I have this object where I need to create unique identifiers ( primary keys ) for updating, retrieving etc from the realm database by identifier. Since realm doesn't support this out of the box I wanted to create my own way of identifying them.

```
class Swing: Object {

    dynamic var latitude : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var longitute : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var speed : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var date : NSDate = NSDate()
}
```

Can I use the NSDate as a unique id or should I go with a new column called id and use UUIDString? and is this always unique for a new object or only per device?

```
dynamic var id = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

What solution would be more failsafe/accurate?

Comment: What's the use case? What is `Swing`?

Comment: If you ran a test of printing out consecutive values for UUIDString you would not need to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably safer to simply have an `NSUUID` as your primary key. They're guaranteed to be unique, and depending on the types of `NSDate` values you're saving to your property, uniqueness definitely can't be guaranteed.

NSUUID is a 128-bit randomly generated value, so even on different devices, the odds of the same string being generated twice is astronomically small.

```
class Swing: Object {
    dynamic var id = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var latitude : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var longitute : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var speed : Double = 0.0
    dynamic var date : NSDate = NSDate()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```